# Is this top suitable for my interview?

Tags: interviewing

I was called this afternoon for an interview at a call center. My interview is 08:30 tomorrow morning. It is entry level to start but as part of the role, I'd be trained and become a supervisor after six months.

As I was in work at the time, on the way home, I purchased a new shirt only to discover the hanger and the shirt do not match in size afterwards. So I have had to search my wardrobe.

I have found a top which is a 2 in 1 effect blouse/jumper. It is similar to this:

[image]

but mine has a rounder collar showing "shirt buttons" and has 3/4 length sleeves. The jumper part is dark purple.

So far, its the only top I can find which I feel comfortable in and looks reasonable decent on. I am teaming it with black trousers and black leather shoes.

Does this meet the expected dress for an interview at a call center? How can I evaluate this in the future?

Comment: __Comments removed.__ This is a professional site, for professional questions and answers. Users are expected to follow site rules for conduct as recently discussed [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322). Continued violations will result in suspension.

Comment: I have made an edit to this question to make it more answerable.  We have other questions about interview dress, so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Update - I worn the top to the interview and since I have now received a job offer i.e was successful, it must have been fine or at least did not affect my interview performance.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a guy so take this for what it's worth.

1. Is it revealing or otherwise inappropriate?
2. Would some "church lady" sneer at it?
3. Would a "creepy guy" whistle at it?

I wouldn't sweat it as long as the answer to the above are no.

Just make sure it's something you're comfortable in.

Comment: Be especially careful about showing your midriff, that is more unprofessional than having cleavage and it is forbidden by many company dress codes.

Comment: Agreed. It also falls under rule #3. :)

Answer (score 6):

Looks fine to me. The thing the model is doing - pointing her face down and looking up, and opening her mouth - seems to be trying to "sexy up" this outfit but it's perfectly reasonable office wear.

Good luck with your interview.